# ubuntuのlocaleの設定でコンソールのみ英語にする

Tags: ubuntu, localization

ubuntu16.04でコンソールのみ英語するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか?
コンソールのエラーメッセージは英語がいいのですが、それ以外は日本語にしたいです

どうすればいいのでしょうか?

Comment: エラーメッセージだけというわけには行きませんが、環境変数 `LC_MESSAGES` を `C` にセットすると、それなりの動作になるかもしれません。

Comment: コンソールとありますが、X上で動く端末エミュレータやSSH越しのシェルも含みますか？（コンソールでは日本語が表示できないから英語にしたいが、端末エミュレータであれば日本語が表示できるから〜という話かなと）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コンソールからだと日本語フォントが表示できないので英語にしたいということかと推測しましたが、`.bashrc` あたりに 環境変数 `TERM` の値によって LANG を切り替えるとうまくいくような気がします。

```
case "$TERM" in
     linux)
          export LANG=C
          ;;
     *)
          export LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
          ;;
esac
```